# Unable to return data from Python EVE API

Tags: python, api, eve

Here is my Python EVE code

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.auth import BasicAuth

class MyBasicAuth(BasicAuth):
    def check_auth(self, username, password, allowed_roles, resource,
                   method):
        if resource == 'auth':
            user = app.data.driver.db['user']
            user = user.find_one({'email': username,'password':password})
            if user:
                return user
            else:
                False
        else:
            return True

app = Eve(auth=MyBasicAuth)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

On successful validation, I'm returning the `user` object but nothing is returned. Where am I going wrong.
Here is the settings.py file

```
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST']

DOMAIN = {
    'user': {
        'schema': {
            'firstname': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            'lastname': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
            'email': {
                'type': 'string'
            },
        'password': {
        'type': 'string'
        },
            'phone': {
                'type': 'string'
            }
        }
    },
    'auth': {
        'schema': {
            'username': {
                'type': 'string'
                },
            'password': {
                'type':'string'
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Authentication and Authorization have nothing to do with returning data. Your `MyBasicAuth` class is only supposed to return `True` or `False` in order to allow the current request to be processed or rejected.

Assuming your client is hitting the `user` endpoint, it will return data if:

1. Your custom auth class returns `True`
2. The `user` collection on the database has documents in it (you are not providing a `datasource` so Eve defaults to the endpoint as datasource name).

Also I am not sure why you are testing if `resource == 'auth'` since you are not setting up an `auth` endpoint in your domain.

To get a head start you might want to check [QuickStart](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html) first, then [Authentication and Authorization](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html) and finally the [RESTful Account Management](http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html) tutorial.

Comment: Hey ..sorry there was an error in `settings.py` updated it to include the auth endpoint. And I'm trying to write an Auth API to validate a username and password and return user details on successful authentication. Since the endpoint which is hitting is not `user` it's `auth` can u tell me how to return user details.